# WooCommerce products Shortcode and "orderby" with price argument

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, price

I added a WooCommerce shortcode to the page I added, to display products sorted by the lowest price for products with discounts / sales, except for products in the "bundle, special offer, free" category
but the product display doesn't work properly,

```
[sale_products category="bundles,special-deals,free" columns="3" orderby="price" order="ASC" operator="NOT IN" paginate=true per_page=18]
```

I made the lowest product price of $ 2
for pages 1 and 2 the product display functions $ 2, but on pages 3 to 6 or so the product display does not work anymore, there are products that are priced at $ 10, $ 5, $ 2, etc.

Is there something wrong with this Shortcode?